# Setting user role (admin/user) in Yii

Tags: php, yii

How can I set the user's role after I login him/her with `Yii::app()->user->login($identity, 0);`?

What I'm asking is how/what does this rule do to check if the user is logged in (`@`) and is administrator (`admin`)?

Code in a random controller:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('users','user'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, like Seydamet said that is a very good tutorial for Yii user writes. In your case

```
'users'=>array('admin'),
```

Means the user with the actual username of admin.

I believe you are trying to use roles. In that case still the link above is perfect.

After loggin in you can do this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/65#hh3 , just assign a role like

```
        if(!$auth->isAssigned('bob',$this->_id))
        {
            if($auth->assign('bob',$this->_id))
            {
                Yii::app()->authManager->save();
            }
        }
```

Then you can do a

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow bob role only access to the view file
            'actions'=>array('view'),
            'roles'=>array('bob')
        ),

        array('deny',   // deny everybody else
            'users' => array('*')
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I set the user's role after I login him/her with
>   Yii::app()->user->login($identity, 0);?

In your WebUser class add method getRole like this:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    private $_model = null;

    function getRole() {
        if($user = $this->getModel()) {

            return $user->role;
        }
    }

    private function getModel(){
        if (!$this->isGuest && $this->_model === null){
            $this->_model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id, array('select' => 'role'));
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }
}
```

Then configure your user component in config

```
'user'=>array(
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    // …
),
```

Then add your AuthManager class (For example I use PhpAuthManager. Not forget configure user component in your config file)

```
class PhpAuthManager extends CPhpAuthManager{
    public function init(){
        // auth.php in config directory consist your roles
        if($this->authFile===null){
            $this->authFile=Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.config.auth').'.php';
        }

        parent::init();

        if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
            $this->assign(Yii::app()->user->role, Yii::app()->user->id);
        }
    }
}
```

Your auth.php like this:

```
return array(
    'guest' => array(
        'type' => CAuthItem::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'Guest',
        'bizRule' => null,
        'data' => null
    ),
    'admin' => array(
        'type' => CAuthItem::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'User',
        'children' => array(
            'guest', // extend all permission form guest user
        ),
        'bizRule' => null,
        'data' => null
    ),
```

);

Then use in your controller filters:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('admin', 'onlyAdmin'),
            // use roles key not user
            'roles'=>array('admin'),
        ),
    );
}
```

and in your actions or templtes:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin')){
    echo "hello, I'm administrator";
}
```

See more in:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/65